# Error trying to log in or create new account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I believe I have a SE account under my email address, broXX@pa.msu.edu. That would not work yesterday and so I tried to create an account from my gmail account raymond.broXX@gmail.com.

That worked and I posted yesterday, but on two computers in two networks, I cannot access the gmail account or the original (it tries to start a new one). Same if I give up and try with Facebook. Each time I get the message:

Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

An unexpected error occurred while logging in. It's not you, it's us. This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

This is all very confusing! What could I possibly doing wrong?